# CSS: Page divided in 3 columns not working on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, multiple-columns

I am trying to have a page divided in 3 columns. The one in the middle will contain the "content" while the other ones will contain a menu and, for this reason, I'd like to have the lateral columns fixed while  the user (vertically) scrolls the page.
The code works on Chrome and on Internet Explorer but on Firefox the column on the left collapse over the column on the right and I can't figure out why.
Here's the code (if you open it on different browser you can notice the difference):
http://jsfiddle.net/mattyfog/6rn3j/4/

HTML

```
<div id="left-col">LEFT</div>
<div id="main">MAIN</div>
<div id="right-col">RIGHT</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 25%;
    background-color: grey;
}

#right-col {
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#left-col {
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
}

#right-col, #left-col {
    position: fixed;
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 140px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thank you guys

Comment: you've given both of them `position: fixed`. Right and main columns are overlapping each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why Firefox is acting strange but I think the correct way to do what you want is something like this:

I removed `float` from `#main` and changed its `padding-left` to `margin-left` and now it's working in on browsers ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rn3j/7/)).

```
#main {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: left;*/
    margin-left: 25%;
    background-color: grey;
}

#right-col {
    float: right;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#left-col {
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}

#right-col, #left-col {
    position: fixed;
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 140px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe that after hours of attemps the solution was so easy. Thanks a lot.